# Count number appearances with another number in several rows

Tags: excel

How can i count how many times one value appears in the same row as another value. for example in this array, how many times does 5 appear with 6. I can see its 3 times but need a formula to count it for me

5 6 12 13 22 35
1 10 25 33 35 2
4 9 10 20 33 2
1 7 10 16 24 1
1 5 6 18 30 22
9 11 14 28 33 5
1 6 15 25 28 5
7 10 17 22 34 7

Comment: What does 'with 6' mean? I only see 6 immediately after 5 twice. What is the criteria?

Comment: Sorry, I may not have made it clear. For instance I have 50 rows of numbers between 1 and 20. I want to count how many times one number appears on the same row as another over those 50 rows. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS` function for "multi-conditional counting" in Excel, for example this formula will count rows which have a `5` in column A and a `6` in the corresponding row in column B

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,5,B:B,6)`

....but as per your comment if you have lottery draw data in `A2:F9` then you can use this formula to get the number of draws including both 5 and 6, assuming 5 in `H2` and 6 in `I2`

`=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT((A$2:F$9=H2)+(A$2:F$9=I2),{1;1;1;1;1;1})=2)+0)`

This assumes that numbers don't repeat in any one row (as is normal with lottery draws).

You can extend this to work for 3 or more search numbers

see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Cheers but not what I mean. I'll put it another way using lottery data as an example:                                             Draw 1 = 5 6 12 13 22 35
Draw 2 = 1 10 25 33 35 2
Draw 3 = 4 9 10 20 33 2
Draw 4  =1 7 10 16 24 1
Draw 5 = 1 5 6 18 30 22
Draw 6 = 9 11 14 28 33 5
Draw 7 = 1 6 15 25 28 5
Draw 8 = 7 10 17 22 34 25
out of these draws, I want to count how many times 'overall' that number 5 appears with number 6; and 18; and 22 etc or number 1 appears with number 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 etc